# My wordpress page extremly slow loading (first load waiting before transfer data)

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, load, hosting

My web site extremely loading slow. Actually my image size and the other attachment's does not bother me. But when first loading, 4 sec later firefox start transferring data (It is occurred in 2-3 days, after routed second domain. I think it is not related but I just wanna add.

Is it related hosting/domain issue, or should I check DNS/nameserver settings?

[PageSpeed Insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeJYf.png)

Actually I want to get rid of first 4 blank image in the test results.

(My hosting's cpanel loads very fast. I think it is not hosting or domain related)

Comment: by the way, I disabled browser caching in .htaccess

'

Comment: [GTmetrix Score](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.yoldarock.com/RLW3dYwK/) - I want to improve time to interactive score (Time to Interactive: 3.6s now)

Comment: It normal to be slow since you dont even cache your website. Optimize your scripts (remove scripts that are not needed). Remove unused fonts, optimize images (compress , use webp , lazy load). Use query monitor to check if there is a problem. Cpanel will load fast except if the server is overloaded. You can ask your hosting about your server performance if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to compress your image with any tools. for example use this site
  [CompressJpeg](https://compressjpeg.com/).
- Secondly, do not the use png file until you don't need any transparency.

Comment: I think my problem is not related jpeg. Images are lazy loaded. Actually I don't want compress my image. Actually it's already compressed for my quality specs. I'll give a shot caching first. And I'll try optimizing scripts.
Actually browser waiting couple seconds with white page and after that starting loading images and css. I want to minimize that white screen time. It maybe caching and script related.

Comment: by the way, above mentioned late loading also occurs when hit the wp-admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. Compress your content such as images.
2. Put your script elements after the body element and before the closing html element.
3. Do not use any CDN or CSS which means you can download and added that path on `function.php`.
4. Install caching plugins.
5. Use lazyloading.